# Convert jQuery script to standalone javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, html-lists

Is it possible for this jQuery code to run as a standalone javascript? This is the only javascript I'd like to use in my project so I'd prefer not to load the entire jquery library just for this 1k script.

```
//chris coyier's little dropdown select-->

$(document).ready(function() {

//build dropdown
$("<select />").appendTo("nav.primary");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
   "selected": "selected",
   "value"   : "",
   "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("nav select");  

// Populate dropdowns with the first menu items
$("div#brdmenu ul li a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value"   : el.attr("href"),
        "text"    : el.text()
    }).appendTo("nav.primary select");
});

//make responsive dropdown menu actually work           
$("nav.primary select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});

});
```

I've tried to find previous answers but most questions are for converting to jquery and not vice-versa :)

Comment: Your jQuery works because of that library you import. You can't do it the other way round.

Comment: You absolutely can rewrite this to be independant from jQuery, but it'll be a LOT larger than 1k. If you're worried about size, you can try Zepto.js (http://zeptojs.com/) which is about 9k and preserves the jQuery syntax. Remove one tiny image from your site, and you've made back the bandwidth.

Comment: sosborn's answer is correct however for what it's worth, If you load the jQuery library directly from the CDN chances are pretty good that the user already has it in the browser cache since many sites already use it.

Comment: I quickly tried zepto however my original script wasnt compatible. I'd prefer not to include any libraries if possible as I'm working on a skin for FluxBB and most of us who use Flux do so because its lightweight :)

Comment: @MattStone—your comment is wrong. A replacement can be less than 2k unminified, see my answer (which is less than 1,000 characters so minified it would be about 0.5kB).

Comment: @RobG Nice work! I'll change my comment to "it'll be a LOT more painful" ;)

Comment: Not more painful to me. :-) Cross-browser scripts aren't that  hard, no harder than learning to use a library efficiently, e.g. the OP's `$(this).find("option:selected").val();` is hugely more efficient as `this.value`, or if you really **must** use jQuery, `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something similar to market's answer. I'm assuming you want to get all the links in UL elements inside the *brdmenu* element. If you only want the first link on the LI elements, just adjust the loop that gets them.

Also, this is not a good idea. Using select elements for links went out of fashion a long time ago, users much prefer real links. Also, when navigating the options using cursor keys in IE, a change event is dispatched every time a different option is selected so users will only get to select the next option before being whisked away to that location. Much better to add a "Go" button that they press after selecting a location.

The main change is to use an ID to get the *nav.primary* element, which I assume is a single element that you should be getting by ID already.

```
function doStuff() {

    function getText(el) {
      return el.textContent || el.innerText;
    }
    var div, link, links, uls;

    // Use an ID to get the nav.primary element
    var navPrimary = document.getElementById('navPrimary');

    // Create select element and add listener
    var sel = document.createElement('select');
    sel.onchange = function() {
      if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {  // -1 for none selected, 0 is default
        window.location = this.value;
      }
    };

    // Create default option and append to select
    sel.options[0] = new Option('Go to...','');
    sel.options[0].setAttribute('selected','');

    // Create options for the links inside #brdmenu
    div = document.getElementById('brdmenu');
    uls = div.getElementsByTagName('ul');

    for (var i=0, iLen=uls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      links = uls[i].getElementsByTagName('a');

      for (var j=0, jLen=links.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        link = links[j];
        sel.appendChild(new Option(getText(link), link.href));
      }
    }

    // Add select to page if found navPrimary element
    if (navPrimary) {
      navPrimary.appendChild(sel);
    }
}

window.onload = doStuff;
```

It's only 28 lines of actual code, which is only 10 more than the original, doesn't require any supporting library and should work in any browser in use (and most that aren't).

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously possible to do those things in straight javascript, but there is no way (that I am aware of) to automatically do that conversion. You will have to go through line by line and do the conversion yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I intend to do but was actually looking for a guide on how to do this. I've since found [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference/) so will take a go at converting the script back to standalone javascript :)

Comment: JQuery is open source so looking at those JQuery methods should give you an idea of what you would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this.

The one thing I'm leaving out is **$(document).ready**, but there are a number of solutions for that available on stackoverflow.  It's a surprisingly large amount of code!

But the other functionality:

```
// build the dropdown
var selectElement = document.createElement('select');
var primary = document.getElementsByClassName('primary')[0];

// create a default option and append it.
var opt = document.createElement('option');
var defaultOpt = opt.cloneNode(false);
defaultOpt.selected = true;
defaultOpt.value = "";
defaultOpt.text = "Go to...";
selectElement.appendChild(defaultOpt);

// populate the dropdown
var brdmenuUl = document.getElementById('brdmenu').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
var listItems = brdmenuUl.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i<listItems.length; i++){
    var li = listItems[i];
    var a = li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var newOpt = opt.cloneNode(false);
    newOpt.value = a.href;
    newOpt.text = a.innerHTML;
    selectElement.appendChild(newOpt);
}

// now listen for changes
if(selectElement.addEventListener){
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', selectJump, false);
}
else if(selectElement.attachEvent){
    selectElement.attachEvent('change', selectJump);
}

function selectJump(evt){
    window.location = evt.value;
}

primary.appendChild(selectElement);​
```

some notes!

1. We're not looking specifically for nav.primary, we're just finding the first occurrence of something with class .primary.  For best performance, you should add an ID to that element and use *getElementById* instead.
2. Similarly with the lists in #brdmenu, we look for the *first* UL, and the *first* A inside each LI.  This isn't exactly what the jQuery does, if you are going to need to iterate more than one UL inside #brdmenu you can use another for loop.

I think that should all work though, there's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BVKQP/)